# Visual Studio won't find class in separate .cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, reference, .net-assembly

I have two classes in separate files in a project I'm working on. Windows forms classes specifically. When I try to use one class from the .cs file, Visual Studio cannot find it. It underlines the line of code and asks if I'm missing a directive or assembly reference. I have no idea why it isn't seeing the other class, as both .cs files are in the same directory. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would be happening and how to fix it?

Also, one of the .cs files is copied from a separate project, so I don't know if that caused a problem somehow.

Comment: Specific error information?  is the file included in the project?  Included as a link?

Comment: Yes, the file is included in the project. It was copied over to the top-level directory.

Error:
Error 4 The type or namespace name 'AddUpdateDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\CIS350\Ch14Prb3\Ch14Prb3Form.cs 92 39 Ch14Prb3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Also, one of the .cs files is copied from a separate project, so I don't know if that caused a problem somehow.

You should check the namespaces involved. My guess is that the one from the other project is in a different namespace. So, if you've got:

```
namespace FirstNamespace
{
    class Foo
    {
        private Bar bar = null;
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace SecondNamespace
{
    class Bar 
    {
    }
}
```

Then in the first class you need:

```
using SecondNamespace;
```

to allow you to use `Bar` without any qualification.

Or - possibly better - you could just change them so they're both in the same namespace.

Better yet, you could avoid copying anything from a different project, and instead use class libraries for code sharing.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it, separate namespaces. I completely forgot to rename the namespace part after I moved it. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case namespace was fixed but still visual studio did not recognized classes.
I solve it by right click on the class file and click 'Include In Project'.

Comment: I had this issue using VSCode... it was as simple as my .cs file accidentally being in a parent directory (to the .csproj file). The linter didn't catch this, but I was still able to compile fine. In VSCode it is sometimes hard to make out directories with the default directory tree menu visuals.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the second file from another project, it could be that the class it contains is in a different namespace.
Add a `using <namespace>` at the beginning of the other file...